# How do i make a global variable with data from an action, with swift

Tags: swift

I want to make a global variable with the data from "sliderValue" how do I do that

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 66.0/255, green: 150.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
}

@IBAction func slider(sender: UISlider) {
    var sliderValue = lroundf(sender.value)
    label.text = "\(sliderValue)"
}
```

Comment: What do u mean here `global variable`?  I mean, what type of Scope of that variable u expecting!!!!

Comment: Im not sure what you mean global variable. When you make a variable in a class or subclass it can only be used in that class. But are you asking how you can access the value of sliderValue from any swift file or class in the app?

Comment: If u just need that slider value to be accessible within the class file . then just declare outside the `func` and within the `class {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the data of `sliderValue` from any file or class, this is how you do it.

*** For structure purposes create a new .Swift file to manage global data variable (example SharedData.swift)**

**FIRST STEP**

In `SharedData.Swift` write the following :

```
class SharedDataRecord {
    class var sharedInstanceRec: SharedDataRecord {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: SharedDataRecord?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = SharedDataRecord()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    var sliderValue : Int
    var sliderName: String = ""
    var sliderAge: Int

}
```

This class will enable you to "save" any data into sliderValue that is an `Int`. At the same time say you had more variable that you wanted to save, so you simply add more variable below it like I did.

**NEXT STEP**

In the `.Swift` file where you gain that `sliderValue` data you need to..

1. Store the `SharedDataRecord` class in a variable
2. Then after you gain the data for `sliderValue` you set that data to the property in the `SharedDataRecord` like I did below.

   ```
    class mainVC : UIViewController {

   var sharedData = SharedDataRecord.sharedInstanceRec

   @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
       override func viewDidLoad() {

           self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 66.0/255, green: 150.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1.0)

       }

       @IBAction func slider(sender: UISlider) {
           var sliderValue = lroundf(sender.value)
           label.text = "\(sliderValue)"

           self.sharedData.sliderValue = sliderValue

       }
   ```

   }

**THIRD STEP**

After that function is run, the `sliderValue` data will be saved in `self.sharedData.sliderValue` and you can use that data anywhere else in the app.

You simply have to add the class into a variable again and just call the property like so :

```
class secondVC : UIViewController {

var sharedData = sharedDataRecord.sharedInstanceRec

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

print(self.sharedData.sliderValue)

}

}
```

Easier Method

```
class viewController : UIViewController {

    var sliderValue : Int = 66


    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 66.0/255, green: 150.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {

        if sliderValue != nil {

            let red = CGFloat((sliderValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0

            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red, green: 150.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1.0)

       } else {

           return

    }

    }

    @IBAction func slider(sender: UISlider) {
        sliderValue = lroundf(sender.value)
        label.text = "\(sliderValue)"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but i should properly redefine my question, i will just make the make the Red color of the background equal to the sliderValue, there must an easier way than that :D

Comment: Im not sure i understand your question exactly haha -_-. You want to change the background color depending on the value of `sliderValue`?

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:66.0/255, green: 150.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1.0), i would change the background using RGB, so if sliderValue is equal to 23 then the red value would be 23

Comment: try the easier method  in my updated answer. Basically `viewWillAppear` will check automatically if there is a value in `sliderValue`. If there is a value then it will create a new RGB color that is stored in `red`. Then it will set the `self.view.backgroundColor` using the variable `red`.

Comment: That is because you declare `sliderValue` inside a function. You need to first declare it in the class (outside the function) and then call it in the function. Check my updated answer above.

Comment: *Class 'ViewController' has no initializers 
*Method does not override any method from its superclass
*Value of type 'Int' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

Comment: The `Class viewController : UIViewController {}` is an example. You need to add whats inside above to your own class for your viewController.

Comment: I've already done that, maybe i should just try to make something more simple, i think this project is to hard for my skill level but thx :D

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is define a variable inside your class. Something like this:

```
var sliderValue: Int
```

I think that is the correct data type for the method you are using but change it as needed.

Comment: So i'm just placing it inside my Viewcontroller class?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use variables in multiple places in your ViewController then you would define it inside the view controller. In this case it has scope for the entire class. If you define it inside a method then it only has scope within that method. As soon as the method completes the variable is out of scope and can't be used any longer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply take it like below

```
var globeRateVal : Float = 1.0
//initialize value by slider default value.
```

then in your code slider method or any where set like this

```
globeRateVal = slider.value
```

Still you have confusion feel free to ask me.